# Temp folder unusable

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, filesystem-corruption

I had mysql-server installed, wordpress was working fine then I tried to install cyberpanel which failed installing mariadb

So I manually tried to install mariadb to know why it failed, it failed again and also broke my mysql, couldn't remove/purge it, couldn't reinstall it either no matter what I did,

After trying a few things here and there including creating backups and removing mysql dirs, now I cannot install anything, culprit being **/tmp** dir:

```
apt install x
E: Unable to mkstemp /tmp/clearsigned.message.PdV08H - GetTempFile (74: Bad message)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

and more interestingly:

```
ls /tmp
ls: reading directory '/tmp': Bad message
```

I cannot install something to pull my data like vsftpd will also fail to install

Server is running Ubuntu 20.04

**Update:** checked dmesg and

```
EXT4-fs error (device loop0): __ext4_find_entry:1541: inode #2: comm lswsctrl: checksumming directory block 0
```

Comment: Have you tried to `fsck`? Compare [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/547194/108618).

Comment: @kamil tried fsck -y /tmp, no output

Comment: What is the output of `findmnt -T /tmp`?

Comment: /dev/loop0 on which fsck says cannot continue, aborting @kamil >"/tmp   /dev/loop0 ext4   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime"<

Comment: To `fsck` ext (aka `e2fsck`) the filesystem must not be mounted. See `man 8 fsck.ext4`. That's why the accepted answer to the linked question used a live USB. Before you unmount or reboot, let's investigate what `/dev/loop0` is. What is the output of `losetup -l /dev/loop0`?

Comment: Sizelimit 0   offset  0    autoclear 1. RO  0   backfile /usr/.tempdisk   dio 0     logsec 512 @kamil and i have already rebooted it a few times

Comment: I guess your `/etc/fstab` contains something like `/usr/.tempdisk /tmp ext4 loop,…`. The troublesome filesystem exists in `/usr/.tempdisk` which is a regular file. Possibly you can `fsck` it (when not mounted). If you can afford losing everything from the current `/tmp` then creating the file and a filesystem anew may be the simplest solution. Can you take it from here? It's late night where I live and for now I cannot assist you further. I will probably be back in several hours. Maybe someone else will help you sooner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131211/discussion-between-asim-and-kamil-maciorowski).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, with [Kamil](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski)'s help, and following what is mentioned in [this website](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-mount-tmp-as-separate-filesystem-with-noexec-nosuid-nodev/), I could fix my problem. Just thought others might find it help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1166423)